# BizTalk map not calling default constructor of helper class used by script functoid at start of transformation

Tags: biztalk

I'm using script functoids in my map. I configured script functoids using external assembly helper method of serializable class. I noticed that when map executes first time then calls Serializable helper class constructor defined in  external assembly and I'm init. default value of class members and works as expected.

In next/second run, class constructor does not get called by map and class members persist value set during last execution of map. I'm using map inside orchestration and my orchestration is not singelton. So, helper class always returning same value to script functoid every time after first execution of my map.

**Please help me how to force biztalk to create new instances of map helper class during every map execution???**

Comment: Could you show us the constructor of your helper class?

Comment: Make the helper class static. This will result in the desired behaviour.

Comment: I don't think anyone can **force** BizTalk to call your code the way you want it. You will have to work with BizTalk, not against it...

Answer (score 0):

The BizTalk runtime caches the extension object instances for a given map type. The constructor will only be called once for each host instance that's using it.

You can, however, create a factory class for your map helper. Call this factory class from a scripting functoid and link the output to an inline C# functoid that stores the object in an instance field in the map. You can the reference that field in other scripting functoids that need to call methods on your helper.

Answer (score -1):

See this post regarding [Biztalk external assembly calls](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/biztalkgeneral/thread/6a5f33ce-d3dd-46ff-aae8-1bc5b484485f). You cannot have a static class - the helper method must be static, but you need to perform your initializations each time in the static method. This is done for state management during rehydration/dehydration.

Comment: I'm not using static class and helper method is also not static. I see map calls instance method every time but does not call default constructor.

Comment: Try using a [static constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Your methods should always be static - even though BizTalk allows non-static methods to be called. This was always confusing to me also.